# Unable to get Publish Permission With Test User Facebook Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish

I want to publish post to user's wall. I know Facebook only allows tester and developers to post on wall. I have already added user to tester list. When I try to get publish permission, it says that user has already granted permission (as shown  in screenshot) and returns. I am not able to get permission or post on wall. Moreover, callback's any method is not called as well.

[image]

**CODE**

I have followed code from Facebook Example [RPSSample](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/RPSSample/src/com/example/rps/RpsFragment.java).

```
//Publish to wall
public void publishResult() {

        registerPublishPermissionCallback();

        if (canPublish()) { //see definition below
            ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(urlToPost))
                    .build();

            ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                   callback.didShareOnFacebookSuccessfully();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // This should not happen
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    showToast(error.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }

//check if user has permission or not
private boolean canPublish() {
        final AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (accessToken != null) {
            if (accessToken.getPermissions().contains(AppConstants.ADDITIONAL_PERMISSIONS)) {
                // if we already have publish permissions, then go ahead and publish
                return true;
            } else {
                // otherwise we ask the user if they'd like to publish to facebook
                new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        .setTitle(R.string.share_with_friends_title)
                        .setMessage(urlToPost)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.share_with_friends_yes, canPublishClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.share_with_friends_no, dontPublishClickListener)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

//If user allows, ask Facebook to grant publish_action permission
    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener canPublishClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                // if they choose to publish, then we request for publish permissions

                LoginManager.getInstance()
                        .setDefaultAudience(DefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
                        .logInWithPublishPermissions(activity,
                                Arrays.asList(AppConstants.ADDITIONAL_PERMISSIONS));
            }
        }
    };

//Callback - Any of the method doesn't call. 
private void registerPublishPermissionCallback() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(
                callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                        if (accessToken.getPermissions().contains(AppConstants.ADDITIONAL_PERMISSIONS)) {
                            publishResult();
                        } else {
                            handleError("Not enough permissions to publish");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        handleError(exception.getMessage());
                    }

                    private void handleError(String errorMessage) {
                        // this means the user did not grant us write permissions, so
                        // we don't do implicit publishes
                        showToast(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

My app is live on console. Please guide what is requirement of Facebook to get publish permission with test user? Thanks.

Comment: Remove you app from facebook and try again, it will work. [How to remove app from facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/170585223002660). After reinstalling it should ask for publish permission instead of screen you have shared.

Comment: Sorry but removing app is not a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to solve the problem. There was no issue in code. It was some setting / permission issue with Facebook app. These are steps I followed:

1. Remove the user from **Test role section** in your Facebook Developer Console.
2. Revoke App's Access by logging into that user's account. Go to **Settings > Apps**. Remove the app from there. You need to wait 10-15 min, since it takes time from Facebook side to revoke access completely.
3. Make your Facebook App in Sandbox mode (you need to do this to perform publish testing).
4. Login your android app using any Facebook account other than app admin. It should throw error that app is in development mode.
5. Add user as Tester in the Facebook Console App. That user may need to approve pending request at his side.
6. Login from that user account. Facebook will now ask you to provide basic information access to the app. After that you can test publishing. You will be able to post on the user's wall successfully.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to check if permission is Granted or not.

```
 String url = "/" + "(userFbID)" + "/permissions";
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), url, null,
                        HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {

                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {



                                try {

                                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(
                                            response.getRawResponse());

                                    JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");

                                    boolean isPermitted = false;

                                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

                                        if (data.getJSONObject(i)
                                                .getString("permission")
                                                .equals("publish_actions")) {
                                            isPermitted = true;

                                            String status = data.getJSONObject(i)
                                                    .getString("status");

                                            if (status.equals("granted")) {

                                                publishResult()

                                            } else {

                                                LoginFacebook();
                                            }

                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if (!isPermitted) {
                                        LoginFacebook();
                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        }).executeAsync();
```

replace user's fb id on place of (userFbID).

If permission is not granted then use this function to ask user for that permission.

```
 private void LoginFacebook() {

            loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();

            loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this,
                    Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));

            loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {



                            publishResult()
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {

                        }

                    });
        }
```